# node and express send json formatted

Tags: json, node.js, express, formatted

I'm trying to send formatted json with express.

Here is my code:

```
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  users.find({}).toArray(function(err, results){
    // I have try both
    res.send(JSON.stringify(results, null, 4));
    // OR
    res.json(results);
  });
});
```

I get the json in my browser but it's a string.
How can I send it so it's readable in the browser?

Comment: JSON is always a string. To get the object back, you have to parse that string on the client side.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You're going to have to set the Content-Type to application/json like this

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    users.find({}).toArray(function(err, results){
        res.header("Content-Type",'application/json');
        res.send(JSON.stringify(results, null, 4));
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks it works with the stringify way. Please edit your post so it will be more clear and I can validate it

Answer (score 106):

try to set the "secret" property `json spaces` on the Node app.

```
app.set('json spaces', 2)
```

This statement above will produce indentation on json content.

Comment: I think JSON.stringify() plus content-type header is the "official" way that one should understand, but this secret property is preferred because it's much cleverer!

Comment: Definitely trick of the day ! Combined with `app.use(express.json())` it's much cleaner in code to have `res.json()` instead of `res.send(JSON.stringify(), null, 4)`

Comment: Most convenient method and easy to turn on/off for dev/prod. Documentation: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.set

Comment: is there a way to make it coloured ?

Comment: @Lucifer, for color, it depends on how you are consuming the endpoint, for example, if you use Google Chrome, you can install an extension to do this

Comment: well I meant from the server side itself. Can my Express app enforce colored json?

Answer (score 7):

Use `type('json')` to set `Content-Type` and `JSON.stringify()` for formatting:

```
var app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  users.find({}).toArray((err, results) => {
    res.type('json').send(JSON.stringify(results, null, 2) + '\n');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem

```
var app = express();
app.set('json spaces', 4)

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  users.find({}).toArray(function(err, results){
      res.json(JSON.parse(results));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sending JSON output as formatted from the server could be undesirable considering resource usage and performance of the server. Especially in production environments.

Instead, you can find a few ways to format the JSON output at client-side.

If you are using Chrome, you can use an extension among [JSON Formatter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa?hl=en), [JSON Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-viewer/gbmdgpbipfallnflgajpaliibnhdgobh), [JSONView](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc?hl=en) or others from Chrome web store.

Firefox provides built-in [JSON viewer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/JSON_viewer) since Firefox 44.

When using `curl` or `wget` in a command line or a shell script, you can pipe the result in JSON into [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

```sh
$ curl http://www.warehouse.com/products | jq .
```

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, you can override `res.json` in a custom middleware that runs before your routes.

To auto-format *all* JSON responses:

```js
app.use('*', (req, res, next) => {
    res.json = (data) => res.type('json').send(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4))
    next()
})

app.get('/route', (req, res) => res.json({ formatted: true })
```

To allow custom formatting based on individual routes or other logic:

```js
app.use('*', (req, res, next) => {
    res.json = (...args) => res.type('json').send(JSON.stringify(...args))
    next()
})

app.get('/tabs', (req, res) => res.json({ formatted: 'tabs' }, null, '\t')
app.get('/spaces', (req, res) => res.json({ formatted: 'spaces' }, null, 4)
app.get('/minified', (req, res) => res.json({ formatted: false })
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you need to `JSON.parse(resp)`