# How to format the response in JSON from NextJS/Express

Tags: express, next.js

I'm using NextJS API Routes and am building for a tutorial. In both production and development, I want the JSON to be formatted.  The original code that does not format the JSON and does include the header I want "application/json" is the following:

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
   ..
   const speakers = [{id: 1, name: 'sp1'},{id: 2, name: 'sp2'}];
   res.status(200).json(speakers);
```

I do want to format the JSON and I have tried the following and it does format the JSON but I can't figure out how to attach the content type header "application/json" to the response.

```
   res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(speakers,null,2));
```

*** Though I tagged this question with express, I think there is a NextJS specific component to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node and express send json formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32679505/node-and-express-send-json-formatted)

Comment: Unfortunately not. I did see that question and tried several of the variations suggested including `res.type('json').send(JSON.stringify(speakers, null, 2));`. All those result in "API resolved without sending a response for /api/speakers, this may result in stalled requests.".  I think that NextJS might not be using express exactly but that's in a level of NextJS I don't really understand.  That is, this is not a pure express question.

Comment: I just found another example and this worked:  `   res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');`

Comment: Doesn't `res.status(200).json(JSON.stringify(speakers,null,2));` do the trick?

Comment: @juliomalves, did not try that.